# Using an IF statement based on a random event

Tags: java

I am drawing a blank on how to code this. I have an array list that randomly picks one of four strings. Then based off that selection I need that to be used in an `IF` statement.

Here is my code, my end goal is that if `TEST3` is randomly selected above. Then it will be saved to platform1 and formatted for display. I then need `TEST3` to be run through the if statement to decide whether or not the other numbers should display.

```
public static String platform() {
    ArrayList<String> plat = new ArrayList<String>();
    plat.add("TEST1");
    plat.add("TEST2");
    plat.add("TEST3");
    plat.add("TEST4");
    String platform1 = plat.get(new Random().nextInt(plat.size()));
    String platform1_format = String.format("%4s", platform1).replace(' ', ' ');
    if (platform1_format.equals("TEST3")) {
        ArrayList<String> bankcodes = new ArrayList<String>();
        bankcodes.add("012");
        bankcodes.add("254");
        String bankcodes1 = bankcodes.get(new Random().nextInt(bankcodes.size()));
        String bankcodes1_format = String.format("%-6s", bankcodes1).replace(' ', ' ');
    } else {
        String bankcodes1 = " ";
        String bankcodes1_format = String.format("%-6s", bankcodes1).replace(' ', ' ');
    }
    return platform1_format;
}
```

Comment: your description doesn't mention the problem at hand, it only mentions your end goal.

Comment: While I have no idea what sense it should make to replace space by space, where is your problem actually?

Comment: my if statement isn't working. I only want the numbers to display if TEST3 is randomly selected.

Comment: What do you mean by "isn't working"? Works fine here.

Comment: Well, in your code you don't output the numbers anywhere, you just assign them to local variables.

Comment: Just use simpler logic - save your `new Random(..)` result and then ask about it in your `if` statement.

Comment: That's where I'm confused because I need to print TEST3 as well as use it as a variable in the if statement, and then print the results of the if statement.

I understand what you're all saying, I'm just not sure how to do that.

Comment: @Tom, What is the purpose of this method: `replace(' ', ' ')`. Why return `platform1_format` it is not final result, not `bankcodes1`?

Comment: @DoNhuVy I am creating a record in a flat file, when I was reading online the replace was to make sure that extra characters didn't get in.  I know that returning bankcode1 is not what should be returning. This is just as far as I got before I got stuck and couldn't figure out what to do next

Comment: I changed the if statement to a Case statement, and realized that I needed to define the variable outside of the statement so that it would be accessible when creating the return.